# Sending and receiving UDP using the same port does not work with the asio library?

Tags: udp, asio

I'm trying to send and receive UDP packets through the same endpoint. As far as I know this should be possible. But I can not get it to work with the asio library (version 1.20.0).

This is what I do:

```
asio::io_context io_context;
asio::ip::udp::socket* udpSendRecvSocket = new asio::ip::udp::socket(io_context, asio::ip::udp::endpoint(asio::ip::udp::v4(), 7782));
asio::error_code ec;

char data[1000];

//
// send packet
//
std::string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
asio::ip::address ip_address = asio::ip::address::from_string(ipAddress);
asio::ip::udp::endpoint remoteTarget_endpoint(ip_address, 5500);
udpSendRecvSocket->send_to(asio::buffer(data, 50), remoteTarget_endpoint, 0, ec);
if (ec) {
    return 0;
}

//
// receive packets
//
size_t avLen = udpSendRecvSocket->available(ec);
while (avLen) {
    asio::ip::udp::endpoint remote_endpoint;
    size_t length = udpSendRecvSocket->receive_from(asio::buffer(data, 1000), remote_endpoint, 0, ec);
    int p = remote_endpoint.port();
    if (ec) {
        return 0;
    }
    avLen -= length;
}
```

The receive does not work correctly. I do receive a packet that I send (from some other app). I know because avLen gets the right value. But when executing the receive_from(), if fails. And the port number in p gets the value 5500. This is the value of the target port of the send_to() call that was executed before.
The strange thing is that when I remove the send_to() call, the receive does work correctly and the p will reflect the correct port number of the sending application.

Is this a bug?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. You are sending data from port 7782 (udpSendRecvSocket is bound to this local port) to port 5500 (remoteTarget_endpoint), yet you expect to receive the data on port 7782.This is like flying from New York to Los Angeles but expecting to arrive at New York.

Comment: I want to send packets from port 7782 to port 5500, but at the same time receive (other) packets on 7782 from 5500. Two way trafic so to say.

Comment: If you want to receive packets on port 5500 you need to have a socket bound to port 5500 - which you don't have. If you want to receive packets on port 7782 you need a socket bound to port 7782 - which you have. You cannot do both things with the same socket since a socket can only bind to a single address.

Comment: No, sorry for misunderstanding. I want to receive and transmit using port 7782.

Comment: Thus receiving on 7782 from 5500.
And at the same time sending from 7782 to 5500.
Port 5500 is handled by some other application. Currently on same computer, later it will be on some other computer.

Comment: As I said I do receive something because size_udpSendRecvSocket->available(ec) indicates the right number of bytes. But then udpSendRecvSocket->receive_from() fails.

Comment: udpSendRecvSocket fails to recv if there are no data to receive. It is expected that data arrive at port 7782, since this is the local port for the socket. Nothing here shows that data get actually send to port 7782. You only show that data get send from port 7782 to port 5500. If there is some external process which is expected to send data to port 7782 then provide information about this process and show that the process actually sends the data you are expected to receive.

Comment: As I stated before: size_udpSendRecvSocket->available(ec) returns a number of bytes. There is indeed an other appplication that send data to 7782. And this available() function shows excatly that amount of bytes. So the packet is received.
I do not understand why receive_from() gives an error while there are bytes in the buffer.